# Prove a property using shift theorem and duality

Tags: fourier-transform, continuous-signals, fourier, self-study, proof

I'm reading [Lectures on the Fourier Transform and Its Applications](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/lectures-on-the-fourier-transform-and-its-applications) and I'm going to prove shift theorem for the inverse Fourier transform using duality. According to the mentioned source, the duality equations are
$$\mathcal{F}f = (\mathcal{F}^{-1}f)^{-} \tag{1}$$
$$\mathcal{F}f^- = \mathcal{F}^{-1}f \tag{2} $$
$$ \mathcal{F}\mathcal{F}f = f^{-} \tag{3}$$
Where $$(\mathcal{F}f)(s) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-2\pi i st}f(t)dt$$ $$(\mathcal{F}^{-1}f)(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{+2\pi i st}f(s)ds$$
And $$f^{-}(t) = f(-t)$$
Using shift theorem which says $$f(t) \leftrightarrow F(s) \implies f(t-b) \leftrightarrow e^{-2\pi isb}F(s) \tag{4}$$ And duality equations I want to show $$F(s) \leftrightarrow f(t) \implies F(s-b) \leftrightarrow e^{2\pi itb}f(t) \tag{5}$$
First of all $\text{(5)}$ seems ambiguous to me but I guess it's $$\mathcal{F}\{ e^{2\pi itb}f(t)\} = F(s - b) \tag{6}$$
It's straightforward to show that directly $$\mathcal{F}\{ e^{2\pi itb}f(t)\} = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-2\pi i st}e^{2\pi itb}f(t)dt = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-2\pi it(s-b)}f(t)dt = F(s-b)$$
But I don't know how to combine duality equations and shift theorem to prove $\text{(5)}$. There is another version of duality which can be found for example [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/47210/duality-of-the-continuous-time-fourier-transform-derivation-and-notation). It says $$x(t) \leftrightarrow X(s) \implies X(t) \leftrightarrow x(-s) \tag{7}$$
Is $\text{(7)}$ same as duality equations i.e. equations $\text{(1)}, \text{(2)}$ and $\text{(3)}$ or they are different from each other?

**Edit:** Equation $\text{(6)}$ is called modulation theorem. Also it seems in $\text{(5)}$ by $F$ we mean $\mathcal{F}^{-1} f$. So it's completely different from $\text{(6)}$. I'm really confused by these similar equations.

**Edit2:** I realized that the other version of duality is same as $\text{(3)}$. I mean the equations $\text{(3)}$ and $\text{(7)}$ are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X(f)=\mathcal{F}\{x(t)\}$ you have, in analogy with Eq. $(7)$,

$$x(f)\Longleftrightarrow X(-t)\tag{1}$$

where we assume that functions with the independent variable $f$ are Fourier transforms of the corresponding functions with independent variable $t$.

Applying $(1)$ to

$$x(t-b)\Longleftrightarrow e^{-2\pi jbf} X(f)\tag{2}$$

gives

$$x(f-b)\Longleftrightarrow e^{2\pi jbt} X(-t)\tag{3}$$

According to $(1)$, $X(-t)$ is the inverse Fourier transform of $x(f)$, so with $g(t)=X(-t)$ and $G(f)=\mathcal{F}\{g(t)\}=x(f)$ you obtain the desired result:

$$G(f-b)\Longleftrightarrow e^{2\pi jbt} g(t)\tag{4}$$

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused. If $X(f)=\mathcal{F}\{x(t)\}$ then what do you mean by $x(f)\Longleftrightarrow X(-t)$?

Comment: @S.H.W: It means that $x(f)$ is the Fourier transform of $X(-t)$, which is a consequence of $X(f)$ being the Fourier transform of $x(t)$.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. Do you think in addition to $\text{(7)}$ we can consider equations $\text{(1)}$ and $\text{(2)}$, which I've quoted, as duality equations?

Comment: @S.H.W: I guess you could say so.